# Angular 6 / RxJs 6 Observable merging that also skips to error block

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I have a login function in my authentication service and I want it to return with some value if the login completes or return the HttpError. That step was easy however, I also want to include if the initial login works, load account details using a second observable. This step is not working for me because if the login fails the code shouldn't also try and load the account details. I tried using the merge function however when errors occur it still calls the other observable. Also even if the login works I still never get a delay from the second observable.

I am having a really hard time adapting to the pipe setup with version 6 of Rxjs and having this many pipes is very confusing to follow.

Login Method:

```
    public Login(LoginData: LoginModel): Observable<HttpErrorResponse | LoginResponse>
  {
    var loginRequest = this.web.post<LoginResponse>('http://localhost:20552/api/token', LoginData).pipe(share());

    return loginRequest.pipe(map((success: LoginResponse) =>
    {
      return new LoginResponse(success.token);
    }), merge(this.LoadAccountDetails())).pipe(catchError((val: LoginResponse | HttpErrorResponse) => of(val))).pipe(map((x: LoginResponse | HttpErrorResponse) =>
    {
      if (x instanceof LoginResponse)
      {
        return new LoginResponse(x.token);
      } else
      { 
        var error = x as HttpErrorResponse;
        return error;
      }
    }));
  }


  public LoadAccountDetails(): Observable<any>
  { 
    return of({}).pipe(delay(5000)); // Simple delay function because I haven't finished this server code yet.
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether the error is emitted as `next` or `error` notification but it's hard to tell from this example.

Also the problem could be that you probably want to use `mergeMap` instead of `merge` because `merge` subscribes immediately when the chain is created which is typically not what you want.

If you use `mergeMap(() => this.LoadAccountDetails())` it'll invoke the callback only when its source emits `next` value.